# How to change the property of first content of List View in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have created an expandable `listView` where I am showing text side by side more likely I wanna show a table of 2 columns there. For that, I have used the expandable list view and so far it looks like this(The image below).
[image: my expandable list view]

But I want to change the color of the first line of this list. something like this(image below).
[image: what i want]

As for code, I have used two text views in a horizontal `Linear Layout` and with a custom adapter I am showing the data in the view. here's the XML.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="item"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Item2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone suggest what should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter if position = 0

```
itemText.setBackgroundColor(int colour);
```

Also you should use RecyclerView instead of ListView